# Django form - only show checkbox's with True values

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, jinja2, django-filter

This image shows how currently **all** 'tags' are displayed whether True or False.
[browser view of checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7tm6.jpg)

I am trying to find a simple way to only display checkboxes for those 'tags' with a true value.

Can I add an 'if' statement to this code in forms.py (e.g. within the widgets Meta, or in CheckboxSelectMultiple()) ?

```
class ProjectForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields  = ['title', 'featured_image', 'description', 'demo_link', 'source_link', 'tags']
        widgets = {
            'tags': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        }
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        for name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'input'})
```

The Project class (model) underlying the ProjectForm only stores the 'True' Tags on a many-to-many relationship.
See image of sqlite showing only 'True' value Tags/Checkboxes are stored with each Project:
[view of sqlite database tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmi77.jpg)

The ProjectForm (shown above) is used to create or update a single project and therefore only displays fields for that single project.  Yet the widget containing the checkboxes is displaying the checkboxes used by all projects (not just the specific project being created/edited).

HTML template Form is as follows:

```
<form class="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {% csrf_token %}    
 {% for field in form %}
    <!-- Input:Text -->
    <div class="form__field">
     <label for="formInput#text">{{field.label}}</label>
      {{field}}
    </div>
 {% endfor %}
 etc.etc........
```

Here is the underlying Project class (model):

```
class Project(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    featured_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, default="default.jpg")
    demo_link = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
    source_link = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)
    vote_total = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    vote_ratio = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    class Meta:
        # ordering = ['-created']
        ordering = ['-created', '-vote_ratio', 'vote_total', 'title']
```

This view that uses the ProjectForm and renders the html template when creating a Project is as follows:

```
def createProject(request):
    profile = request.user.profile
    form = ProjectForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newtags = request.POST.get('newtags').replace(',', " ").split()
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            project = form.save(commit=False)
            project.owner = profile
            project.save()

            for tag in newtags:
                tag, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag)
                project.tags.add(tag)
            return redirect('account')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'projects/project_form.html', context)
```

The view code for updating a project is as follows (renders same html template as creating Project):

```
def updateProject(request, pk):
    profile = request.user.profile
    project = profile.project_set.get(id=pk)
    form = ProjectForm(instance=project)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newtags = request.POST.get('newtags').replace(',', " ").split()
        
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=project)
        if form.is_valid():
            project = form.save()
            for tag in newtags:
                tag, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag)
                project.tags.add(tag)
            return redirect('account')

    context = {'form': form, 'project': project}
    return render(request, 'projects/project_form.html', context)
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think you can do something like {% if field.value %} in the template

Answer (score 0):

in your template you can render a value only if it is true

```
<form class="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}    
{% for field in form %}
   {% if field.field.widget.input_type == 'checkbox' %}
       {% if field.value %}  
            <!-- Input:Text -->
            <div class="form__field">
                <label for="formInput#text">{{field.label}}</label>
                {{field}}
            </div>
       {% endif %}
   {% else %}
       <!-- Input:Text -->
       <div class="form__field">
           <label for="formInput#text">{{field.label}}</label>
           {{field}}
       </div>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you - it is very helpful - although the If conditionals excluded all of the form fields except for the checkboxes (both checked and unchecked).  But it gave me the idea to split out into two 'for loops' ....the first excludes the checkboxes and the second 'for loop' only includes the checkboxes.  Now what is needed is the 'inner If conditional' (in the checkbox only 'for loop') to only display checkboxes that are checked - i tried:  `code` {% if field.value != Null %} `code`  and `code` {% if field.value == True %} `code`  and  `code` {% if field.value == 'True' %} `code`.

Comment: Any further suggestions greatly appreciated !   I wanted to upvote your response but dont as yet have enough reputation - so thanks again!

Comment: glad I was able to help. You should be able to mark this answer as correct.

Comment: well it was opposite to correct - your code actually removed everything from the form except just the problem.  It was helpful as it gave me an idea to separate out the problem.  Now I am looking for a solution to just the problem without the added complexity of other form fields.  So my unanswered question is still the same.  Does someone know how to display just the checkboxes that are checked.

Comment: oh. I didn't realize that there were other input fields i updated my code to reflect that

Comment: At first glance it seems that the code: {% if field.value %}   might work (but doesnt - all True and False checkboxes still show)  There is a many-to-many relationship between the Tag model and the Project, which may be whats making it a little more tricky.

Comment: try `{% if field.value == True %}`

Comment: or `{% if field.field.widget.value != None %}`

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestions !  unfortunately when used none of the checkboxes were shown.  Grateful for further suggestions.